# Why was this VLQ flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-flags

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029011/get-thumbnail-url-from-image-url/32065996#32065996) to my question as VLQ, simply because it did not provide an answer to my question. I found it quite obvious when the answer stated `I don't know how to get Thumbnail Url for a particular image` when my question was `How do I query the MediaStore for the thumbnail url associated with my image URL?`?

However, the answer provided a piece of code that *might* solve the stated problem. Is this reason enough to be disputed as VLQ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a moderator had reviewed this answer, you almost certainly would have gotten:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Here's a good rule of thumb: VLQ flags are for answers that are obviously bad *if you have no knowledge of the subject whatsoever*. Things like: gibberish (asdfasdf), a link with no explanation, sentences about a totally unrelated topic (did you see how the mets almost blew it in the 9th inning tonight?). This answer is none of these.

If the answer is relevant to the question, and the user is trying to help, and they are just straight up *wrong* / *doesn't have the foggiest on how to solve your problem*, the correct thing to do is **downvote**.

All that said, you didn't get a moderator to review it, it was disputed by the community. [Here is the review for that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9200865)

Three Looks OK + 1 Recommend Deletion = disputed flag. `nuff said.